# Angular open modal doesn't get focused

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

Within my ts file i open a boostrap modal using the `.open` command.

Then upon pressing the save button another modal gets open and the previous one gets closed.

Here the problem is that the first modal recieves focus on itself and the elements inside it BUT second modal doesn't get focus!

Here is what is happening:

- I click a button and i open a modal `A`
- In modal `A` i have some html elements including two buttons to save and close the modal
- If i click the save button from modal `A` this modal will get closed and another modal will open
- This second opened modal doesn't get focus when pressing TAB

**Here is a stackblitz**: [StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xzlria?file=src/app/app.component.html)

How this stackblitz works:

- If you click the first button is going to open the modal A
- then clicking save on that modal will open another modal B
- Inside modal B if you try to tab is going to tab on the elements in the background WHY?

I want to give my second modal focus. I tried with `Directives` and other things that angular suggest but i haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already checked bootstrap documentation, and there is no `focus` related thing we can use.

You will need to use the `setTimeout` function with `0ms` to force the `openSecondModal` to run on a different execution cycle. Basically, we need to add a bit of delay for the first modal to close properly before open the second one.

This is a well-known hack. Hopefully, we can write code without using it one day in the future.

```js
modalRef.componentInstance.closeModal.subscribe(() => {

 modalRef.close();

 setTimeout(() => {
   this.openSecondModal();
 }, 0);

});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this works for now. Have to wait on bootstrap to do something about it tho. I was going crazy trying to figure it out... BIG thanks!!!!